# An error occurred when MySQL used leftjoin

Tags: mysql

When I use the left join in mysql, there are two pieces of data, but I'm sure only one will come out

sql is

```
SELECT bs.id,distribute_user_id,manager_id,phone,manager_name 
FROM   bank_integral_distribute_serial bs 
         LEFT JOIN manager mi ON bs.distribute_user_id = mi.manager_id 
WHERE bs.phone = "13978836385"
```

[image]

Respective data sql is

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    bank_integral_distribute_serial 
WHERE   distribute_user_id="1475118915817316353"
```

[image]

sql is

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    manager 
WHERE   manager_id = "1475118915817316353"
```

[image]

I also check the mobile phone number, and there is only one

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp9iM.png)

Questions:
Why are there two pieces of data

Comment: MYSQ won't produce 2 rows/and or not in that format- do you have a presentation layer?

Comment: *An error occurred* - what error?

Comment: You have two distinct rows and the manager name is different in those two rows. Did you have another table in the mix for the first screenshot which was used for Manager name? Looks to me that the manager name is a time series data. You may want to pull the latest manager rather than all

Comment: There are no views in my database. But there is an index in my table, and the manager_ Name exists in only one table, not in other tables。

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the MySQL comparison types are inconsistent.

you can see

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

distribute_user_id The original table is bigint :  manager_id is varchar

```
SELECT IF("1475118915817316353"=1475118915817316354,"equal","unequal") //The results are equal

SELECT IF("1475118915817316311"=1475118915817316360,"enqual","unequal") //The results are equal

//left：[1475118915817316224，1475118915817316480] The results are equal, both with the right side
SELECT IF("1475118915817316480"=1475118915817316360,"enqual","unenqual")
```